# Add HTML on every character line by line

Tags: html, bash, csv

I have a CSV file and I read the file line by line.

Let's say the line reads:

```
10h50 10 15 20
```

What I would like to get is:

```
<tr> <th scope="row">10h50</th> <td>10</td> <td>15</td> <td>20</td> </tr>
```

I started something but not sure if it is the best way.
I have the file `result.csv` with :

```
 10h50,10,15,20
 10h51,11,15,22
 10h52,12,16,30
```

The idea was to :

```
cat result.csv | sed 's/,/ /g' > temp.csv
```

Then :

```
awk '{print $1}' temp.csv > time.csv
awk '{print $2}' temp.csv > col1.csv
awk '{print $3}' temp.csv > col2.csv
awk '{print $4}' temp.csv > col3.csv
```

On `time.csv`

```
cat time.csv | sed 's/^/<tr> <th scope="row">/' | sed 's/$/<\/th> <\/tr>/' > new_time.csv
cat col1.csv | sed 's/^/<td>/' | sed 's/$/<\/td>' > new_col1.csv
cat col2.csv | sed 's/^/<td>/' | sed 's/$/<\/td>' > new_col2.csv
cat col3.csv | sed 's/^/<td>/' | sed 's/$/<\/td>' > new_col3.csv
```

then :

```
paste new_date.csv new_col1.csv new_col2.csv new_col3.csv | column -s $'\t' -t > final_result.csv
```

Any advise ?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @AustenHolland  I did update and show what I tried to do so far... please advise if there is a better way to do what I am looking for.

Comment: @AustenHolland I don't want any code... I just need advise or guidance... the code is there already... but is there a better way ?

Comment: pluse-uno for showing your code! .... but ... ouch!!! You now have two good answers below, showing you basically that your goal should always be to read data once, reformat it and the print it out without any intervening use of other shell processes. If you're going to continue this kind of work, work thru the [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and you'll soon be writting efficient and easily maintained code. Good luck.

Comment: Each time you use `awk`, `sed`, `cat`, etc you are having the "expense" of the system starting a program. The preferred method it to write one program to handle one problem. Sometimes it is easier to chain mutiple programs togehter using `|` (pipes), that is just a matter of experience and evaluating other trade offs. Try to solve general problems (with a program) and then chain them together with pipes. For your current case, you only need a single program `awk -f myawkScript inputFile > outputFile`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a loop / using a script, this is fairly easy.

With an input csv `result.csv`:

```
10h50,10,15,20
10h51,11,15,22
10h52,12,16,30
```

and the bash script as:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 || [ -n "$col1" ];
do
    echo "<tr> <th scope=\"row\">$col1</ht> <td>$col2</td> <td>$col3</td> <td>$col4</td> </tr>"
done < result.csv
```

You will get a result of:

```
<tr> <th scope="row">10h50</ht> <td>10</td> <td>15</td> <td>20</td> </tr>
<tr> <th scope="row">10h51</ht> <td>11</td> <td>15</td> <td>22</td> </tr>
<tr> <th scope="row">10h52</ht> <td>12</td> <td>16</td> <td>30</td> </tr>
```

Comment: I see, in my case I have 21 columns so can I do that : `for i in {1..21}
do 
 awk '{print $("${i}"+2)}' result.csv > col"${i}".csv
done `  where $3 will match with col1 ... ?

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env awk -F, -f
BEGIN {f="<tr> <th scope="row">%s</th> <td>%d</td> <td>%d</td> <td>%d</td> </tr>\n"}
{printf f, $1, $2, $3, $4}
```

give execute permmission and invoke like

myscript file.csv